# In Canada, does a frontcountry campground kitchen shelter typically include a freezer?

Tags: camping, shelter, canada

In European campgrounds, it is common that there is a kitchen shelter with a freezer, where people who camp without electricity can freeze their ice packs, in order to subsequently use those with cool bags for refrigeration.

[The Parks Canada website for Gros Morne National Park](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/nl/grosmorne/visit/visit4.aspx) indicates that each of the frontcountry campgrounds has a kitchen shelter.  Does such a kitchen shelter typically have a freezer with the aforementioned purpose?

Comment: I would say that this would be uncommon in Canada. However, it is fairly common that you can buy ice packs at the park's headquarters or at the nearby amenities. People will used that to refrigerate their coolers.

Comment: another 'cool' trick is to bury your food (simply dig a hole, insert the food container or bags) you can close it using either a plank or using branches, leaves and dirt.

Comment: @HTDutchy  I've also seen people cool their beverages in rivers (and lose it after a sudden rise in water levels).

Comment: @gerrit and thats why you always tie a string to the bottle. When at anchor I lower a bottle of prosecco to the bottom of the river (5meters deep), ice cold!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there won't be anything electrical.  A front country kitchen will usually contain:

- a wood burning stove
- 2-4 picnic tables
- food storage lockers
- a bear proof trash container (nearby)

Depending on the park there may be a woodpile next to the kitchen. Food storage lockers are also dependant on the park and the wild life situation (e.g. bears, racoons), and are more likely to be found at backcountry or walk-in campsites.

The kitchens themselves are open concept, usually about 10m X 5m in size with a wall that's about 1.5m high and then open space until the roof, which means a lateral wind will blow into the kitchen.  This is to stop people from sleeping in them and to avoid smoke problems (a lot of people don't know how to work a wood stove).

[image: Front-country kitchen at Cascade Ponds, Banff National Park. April, 2014]

Source: I live in Banff National Park and have camped in just about every National Park from East to West. In fact, I had a BBQ in one last night, as you can see from the above photo.

Comment: What are walk-in campgrounds?

Comment: Paul: sorry, it should be walk-in campsites. They are campsites where you can't drive your car right up to where you will set up your tent. The walk can be anything from 10m feet to 2km.